# add gRPC JSON Transcoding to exisitng C# gRPC Server. Having problem with importing google api's

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm trying to add JSON Transcoding to a gRPC Server simple test using greet.proto that was working perfectly (except for the fact that I can't connect to it from the outside on Windows 2016 Server due to the HTTP/2 issue.  Server 2016 does Not seem to fully support it for gRPC, but Transcoding give me HTTP/1).

I'm using a GrpcShared shared project class library to store my Proto file between a Console client, Maui client and WPF client.

It was working perfectly before I added the changes for JSON Transcoding.

The GrpcShared class library project just had the example greet.proto file in the first level.  No Protos folder.

I added a google folder and an api folder inside and placed annotations.proto and http.proto (the latest versions I believe) inside the google/api folders.

When I try to compile the GrpcShared class project, I get an error of:

Error    CS0234    The type or namespace name 'Api' does not exist in the namespace 'Google' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    GrpcShared    G:\Projects\GrpcService\GrpcShared\obj\Debug\net7.0\Greet.cs    33    Active

which is of course the generated file.

The GrpcShared project definition is as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
 
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.22.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.52.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.53.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
 
 
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="HelloReply.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <SupportedPlatform Include="browser" />
    <Protobuf Include="greet.proto" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I found an example project for JSON Transcoding.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Transcoder

I followed their basic setup and also the slightly more recent video from .NET that demonstrates the feature:

https://youtu.be/et_2NBk4N4Y

One line in the example project definition perplexes me?

```
<Protobuf Include="..\Proto\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" Link="Protos\greet.proto" />
```

as there Is no 'Proto' folder in the project?  Only the 'Protos' folder and the above line refers to .. Both?

I've tried moving the annotations.proto and http.proto to the main level and changing the import of annotations.proto but .. that just made things worse?

So I'm a but stumped on something that is obviously Trivial and fixed with a few lines of code .. but Not obvious to Me!!

Comment: I'm not a .NET developer ... The `Transcoder` example works for me (building and running with a container). I had to Google and make some tweaks to the code to build under `net7.0`. IIUC (see [Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/json-transcoding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#overview)) ASP.NET core (!) includes gRPC JSON transcoding extensions to support exposing gRPC methods as REST.

Comment: Your server does not appear to use `AspNetCore` and so -- I think -- you're going to need either to switch to ASP.NET or find an implementation of the transcoder perhaps using Envoy [gRPC-JSON transcoder](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter).

Comment: I was able to get the Transcoder example to work by adding a few Using statements.    Hopefully I'll be able to use that starting point and get an ASP.NET Core app running on Windows 2016 server - which Does support Core .. and who knows .. maybe even gRPC using HTTP/2 if Microsoft somehow enabled it due to popular demand?

Comment: However I'm pulling my hair out over one issue.

In the physical folder structure there is a 'Proto' folder that contains the greet.proto and a 'google' folder and 'api' folder inside containing 'annotations.proto' and 'http.proto'

However, the project contains a 'Protos' folder which maps in Properties to repos\Transcoder\Server\Protos\ .. and 'Protos' does NOT EXIST??

and the project file shows:

    <Protobuf Include="..\Proto\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" Link="Protos\greet.proto" />

and mentions this non-existent 'Protos' folder.

Comment: And 'show all files' does Not show the annotations.proto or http.proto or the google or api folders?

So .. I'm Very confused by this and how it even works??   It makes No sense to me??

Comment: I don't understand why that project has `Link="Protos`. You're correct that the physical folder is called `Proto` and it is correctly structured to act as the root folder for the project's protos.

Comment: Yes!  There's something 'magical' about how it's setup as when I've tried to import the annotations.proto from another project where I used actual folders with the correct names which Are visible in 'show all files' I get that 

Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Api' does not exist in the namespace 'Google' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

error which I just Cannot get around? 

I've been researching and this 'protos' folder in this project seems to be a special 'solution folder' virtual folder.  The documents on using that feature are less than useful?

Comment: the JamesNK author of that example is James Newton-King who I believe authored Json.NET so .. he knows what he's doing and his videos on .NET YouTube are incredibly useful.   But .. I just wish he had Commented on .. Why .. he used this virtual folder with a slightly different name for an Example file where users are trying their first test case of the JSON Transcoding feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the transcoding example working by adding some missing using statements.

The problem with the 'api' error was in the way I setup the Protos structure.

The virtual Protos folder (possibly called 'Solution Folders') gets Created by this line in the project:

```
    <Protobuf Include="..\Proto\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" Link="Protos\greet.proto" />
```

When setup 'correctly' as in the example, the api and google physical folders will never show up in the solution explorer .. even with 'show all files' on.

So follow that transcoding example github project Exactly using the Exact same file structure .. to setup json transcoding.